# Using 3 External monitors on my macbook pro, problem with DVD player

Tags: display

I am running 3 external monitors off of my macbook pro 10.6.8. When I try to watch a DVD, the player slides down to my macbook pro. Want to play it on a larger monitor. Possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

When you are in DVD Player, `<command>-F` to exit full screen mode.  Then drag the window to the monitor you want to use and `<command>-F` to switch back to full screen mode.