# Late 2013 MacBook Pro Retina + 2 Thunderbolt displays + Apple Cinema Display @2560x1440?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I saw this answer by griewei here:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/124479/81640

Unfortunately I don't have enough rep to comment.

What I would like to do is something similar e.g.
 - one latest greatest Mac Book Pro Retina
 - 2x Thunderbolt Displays
 - 1 Apple Cinema Display via HDMI adapter etc.

@griewei said he was doing this and it was working; does anyone know if the Apple Cinema display is scaled at 2560 x 1440 in this configuration?

I know it was not possible in Mountain Lion but I heard it was possible in Mavericks

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is my current setup with a late 2013 MacBook Pro
[image]

Comment: I'm probably a little to the game and you might not be using this set up anymore. Do you recall if your mac spins up its fan crazily with 3 screens attached or becomes super laggy?

Comment: It was not laggy, at all, but if I remember well the fan were under constant usage. Not at the maximum speed, but also not completely silent. I was using a stand that kept the Mac in vertical position, maybe this was helping to cool the Mac down and maybe without this the noise would have been louder, but this is just a speculation