# Run two 4K and one non-4K external display from late 2013 Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, display, hardware, thunderbolt

I have a late 2013 Macbook Pro with both the Intel Iris Pro integrated graphics and the NVidia Geforce 750M dedicated GPU. I run two 4k displays, one at 60Hz through a thunderbolt bolt and one at 30Hz through HDMI. I have one open thunderbolt port, and would like to add a 3rd external display. I know that it is possible to run three external displays from this model (see [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111112/how-to-use-3-external-monitors-on-15-late-2013-macbook-pro-retina), [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEkQtwIwBWoVChMI57W-87XjxgIViS-ICh15ZAZk&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DP_Ct3nzQg4w&ei=bZ2pVafLPInfoAT5yJmgBg&usg=AFQjCNFPqGQoBOSam0X0kCT5LV9htPKOFA&sig2=mxT3hhb1b1-S6LqhpTodUQ)), but I also know that it is not possible to run three 4k displays (see [here](http://www.imore.com/using-multiple-4k-displays-your-macbook-pro)).

My question:

**Is it possible to run three external displays, one at 4k/60hz, one at 4k/30Hz, and one at some other resolution/refresh-rate? If so, what is the max resolution/refresh supported for the third monitor?**

Comment: If you can daisy chain the monitors it will work, connecting via thunderbolt to thunderbolt of the 4ks and if the 3rd doesn't have the same method of connection, use the port you are working with. The idea is that thunderbolt technology allows daisy chaining the monitors. So if the ports are available, that is your answer.

Comment: @fingaz Thanks for your input. To be clear, I already have a free thunderbolt port-- I'm not sure why I would need to daisy chain. According to my above references, however, when both thunderbolts and the HDMI port are used simultaneously with three 4K monitors, only two of the monitors work (one of the thunderbolt monitors goes dark). I am wondering whether if I plug a non-4K third monitor into my open thunderbolt port I can expect it to function. Or is there some reason that daisy-chaining would work but not using the open port directly?

Comment: I believe that you would only need to use the one port if you daisy chain all the displays. Once again connecting them via thunderbolt is best. The power is shared between the displays instead of just the main logic board of the MBP

Answer (score 1):

You are outside "supported" territory with using three screens on that hardware.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204154 - thunderbolt FAQ
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206587 4k and 5k and beyond

That being said, you can try connecting things and Apple hardware is known to run more displays than the "support" document allows. Usually it's due to driver updates that can still juggle all the connections but that the performance isn't there or you end up with glitches like frozen screens or just not the frame rates Apple likes to see on supported hardware combination.